# Can you edit the Value property of a named excel object with VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

```
 ThisWorkbook.Names("numWorkersCompEntries").Value = ThisWorkbook.Names("numWorkersCompEntries").Value + 1
```

I would like to store an incrementing variable in the name manager rather than storing it somewhere in the spreadsheet so that I can manipulate it by name. The above code seems intuitive to me but I am getting a type mismatch. Any ideas? Thanks for any help you can provide.

--Drake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your code a bit, you'll see that the values of a single numeric are actually stored as a string, so you're trying to add a string, which Excel isn't happy about.  You can try something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim namedValue As Variant

namedValue = ThisWorkbook.Names("Foo").Value

ThisWorkbook.Names("Foo").Value = Mid(namedValue, 2, Len(namedValue)) + 1

Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Names("Foo").Value
End Sub
```

Which seemed to have the expected results on my test sheet...just make sure you have a named range of "Foo" to test.  Obviously tweak to suit your situation, but hopefully it will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a practical reason why VBA treats the 1 as a string? I have used Ruby and JavaScript in the past and never had a problem like that with ints.

Comment: @user2707702 Unfortunately I have no insight as to why VBA does that.  Hopefully someone more versed than me will come along and be able to shed some light on it.